# shell script network construction error : not found, : file name too long

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, networking, network-programming

I tried to build a network using a shell script

However, I got an error like the image(:not found, : file name too long)

I've been wandering for days, where and how to fix it.

[image]

---

```
#!/bin/bash

sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

hn=$(hostname)

echo $hn

case $hn in

"node0")

echo"

auto lo


iface lo inet loopback


auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.137.8

netmask 255.255.255.0

network 192.168.137.0

gateway 192.168.137.1



auto eth1

iface eth1 inet static

address 10.0.30.9

netmask 255.255.255.0

network 10.0.30.0


gateway 10.94.30.8

">/etc/network/interfaces

;;



"node1")

echo"

auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.137.9

netmask 255.255.255.0


network 192.168.137.1

gateway 192.168.137.1



auto eth1

iface eth1 inet static

address 10.94.10.8

netmask 255.255.255.0

network 10.94.10.0

gateway 10.94.10.9

">/etc/network/interfaces

;;



"node2")

echo"

auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static

address 10.94.10.9

netmask 255.255.255.0

network 10.94.10.0

gateway 10.94.10.8



auto eth1

iface eth1 inet static

address 10.94.20.8

netmask 255.255.255.0

network 10.94.20.0

gateway 10.94.20.9

">/etc/network/interfaces

;;



"node3")

echo"

auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static

address 10.94.20.9

netmask 255.255.255.0

network 10.94.20.0

gateway 10.94.20.8



auto eth1

iface eth1 inet static

address 10.94.30.8

netmask 255.255.255.0

network 10.94.30.0

gateway 10.94.30.9

">/etc/network/interfaces

;;

esac

echo"

nameserver 192.168.137.1

search localdomain

">/etc/resolv.conf

systemctl restart networking.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the `heredoc` (here document) approach to create your output files instead of `echo`. For example,

```
"node1")
cat << EOF > /etc/network/interfaces
All lines from here to the line before the EOF below will be written to the file.
... multiple lines deleted ...
  This last line is indented by two spaces.
EOF
;;
```